# Run Spring Boot application as normal java application without spring boot loader

Tags: java, spring-boot

I wonder is it possible to run spring boot application as a normal java executable jar without spring boot loader?
For example I have next directory with jars:

```
/my-app-dir/main.jar
/my-app-dir/dependencies/spring-core.jar
/my-app-dir/dependencies/apache-tomcat.jar
...
```

where main.jar contains only application classes and directory dependencies contains all required runtime dependencies including spring and spring-boot ones.
And I would run it as usual:
`java -cp /my-app-dir/main.jar:./my-app-dir/dependencies/* com.mypackage.subpackage.MainApplication`

When I do so, spring boot app is loading but cannot find beans and resolve beens tree.

Comment: No, it is not possible to run a Spring Boot application as a normal Java executable JAR without a Spring Boot loader. The Spring Boot loader must be in your classpath in order to start a Spring Boot application. For a Spring Boot application to start, the Spring Boot loader offers a wide range of capabilities, including performing classpath scanning, creating the application context, and managing dependencies.

Comment: it is possible to run a Spring Boot application as a normal Java executable JAR without using the Spring Boot Loader, it requires a lot of manual configuration and initialization of dependencies, properties, and application context. Therefore, it is not recommended, and it is always better to use the Spring Boot Loader to run Spring Boot applications.
So no don't do that

Comment: @Karim, do you have an example how to do it manually?

Comment: @rvit34 honestly never done it myself and it's better to avoid it altogether, your issue feels like you need to rethink what's the thing you actually want to achieve. but something like this should work:

java -cp /my-app-dir/main.jar:/my-app-dir/dependencies/* -Dspring.config.location=/my-app-dir/application.properties com.mypackage.subpackage.MainApplication

Comment: and you need to add every env variable to the command too, and look up other variables that spring needs to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible and supported. It's what happens in your IDE when you run you application's main method directly or when you use the run support in Spring Boot's Maven and Gradle plugins.

There's a [section in the reference documentation describing how to explode the packaged archive and run the main class directly](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#container-images.efficient-images.unpacking). It's written in the context of container images, but it applies to other deployment approaches as well.